# VoiceOver adding incomprehensible words

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I am using Voice Over in my app and making an announcement when the screen shows. The elements on my screen have special Voice Over labels that I have set manually.
I have a view containing a button and an image that overlap and only enabled Voice Over for the button.
The label updates depending on a certain status returned by the backend:

```
  myBtn.accessibilityLabel = "Connected".localized
```

and

```
  myBtn.accessibilityLabel = "Disconnected \(status)".localized
```

Status can either take "moderate" or "low" as values.
When I enable VO and test this out, I hear "Disconnected low" then VO proceeds by adding some words such as "V X star V X" or sometimes even "Logo V X percent X".

I have no idea where this is coming from. I tried debugging and looking for possible reasons but it does not make sense.

Anyone ever faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing:

```
myBtn.accessibilityHint = nil
```